# The PUT request in my Expressjs app is not being recognized or called through api

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a comment route using express.js server
my server.js file has 2 routes:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// routes
app.use('/profile', require('./routes/profile.cjs')());
app.use('/comment', require('./routes/comment.cjs')());
```

and this path is called the comment route at routes.comment.cjs, which has the following PUT request:

```
router.put('/:commentId', async function (req,res, next){
        //some logic
})
```

When I try to call this put via an API with a parameter called commentId, it cannot be reached and will not be called.
This happened with me previously, and it was solved by changing the order of the routes in app.js but I tried that now, and it won't work.

Comment: Can you share what is the URL you are trying to call and what is the response you are getting back?

Comment: The URL that I'm trying to call through postman is:
localhost:3000/comment/63f541b5b26eb255d80378e0
Where the last part is the commentId.
And the response I'm getting is a 404 page not found.